# Preventing overlapping of labels using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, math, three.js

I have textured image to a sphere and attached label to the image, but some of the labels are overlapped, I 
want to seperate the labels, without changing the values of "lon" and "lat". I need to know how to seperate the labels or
how to reposition the label. and also I have uploaded the image (link). And also I have uploaded the full code.
please help me with the problem.

[image: image link]

css code used in this program

```
div.spritelabel {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
color:#0000FF;
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:normal;
line-height:15px;
text-align: left;
padding:5px;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
background:rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.8 );
}
a:link {color: brown; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: none;}
a:visited{color: green; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: none;}
a:hover{color: red; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: underline;} 
a:active {color: yellow; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: underline;}
```

javascript code

```
function createsphere() 
{
var spriteboxes = [];
var sprite,controls,scene,camera,renderer;
var spritearray = [];
spritearray[0] = {"name": "North", "lat":0, "lon": 10};
spritearray[1] = {"name": "south", "lat":0, "lon": 20};
spritearray[2] = {"name": "East", "lat":0, "lon": 30};
spritearray[3] = {"name": "west", "lat":0, "lon": 40};
spritearray[4] = {"name": "North-west", "lat":0, "lon": 45};
spritearray[5] = {"name": "North-east", "lat":0, "lon": 47};
spritearray[6] = {"name": "south-east", "lat":0, "lon": 50};
function convertlatlonToVec3(lat, lon)
{
    lat = lat * Math.PI / 180.0;
    lon = -lon * Math.PI /180.0;
    return new THREE.Vector3(
        Math.cos(lat)* Math.sin(lon),
        Math.sin(lat)* Math.sin(lon),
        Math.cos(lat));

}

function labelBox(Ncardinal, radius, domElement)
{
    this.screenVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    this.position = convertlatlonToVec3(Ncardinal.lat,Ncardinal.lon).multiplyScalar(radius);
    this.box = document.createElement('div');
    a = document.createElement('a');
    a.innerHTML = Ncardinal.name;
    a.href ='http://www.google.de';
    this.box.className = "spritelabel";
    this.box.appendChild(a);

    this.domElement = domElement;
    this.domElement.appendChild(this.box);
}

labelBox.prototype.update = function()
{
this.screenVector.copy(this.position);  
this.screenVector.project(camera);

var posx = Math.round((this.screenVector.x + 1)* this.domElement.offsetWidth/2);
var posy = Math.round((1 - this.screenVector.y)* this.domElement.offsetHeight/2);

var boundingRect = this.box.getBoundingClientRect();

//update the box overlays position
this.box.style.left = (posx - boundingRect.width) + 'px';
this.box.style.top = posy + 'px';



};





function init() 
        {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            camera.position.y = 1;
            camera.position.z = 5;

            var width = window.innerWidth;
            var height = window.innerHeight;
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
            renderer.setSize(width, height);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            var radius = 2.5;
            var spheregeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 20, 20, 0, -6.283, 1, 1);
            var texture =  THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture ('Sample Images/rbi00000083.jpg');
            texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
            var spherematerial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
            var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(spheregeometry, spherematerial);

            scene.add(sphere);
            scene.add(camera);
            scene.autoUpdate = true;

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI/4;
            controls.maxPolarAngle = 3*Math.PI/4;

            for(var i = 0; i< spritearray.length;i++)
            {
                var Ncardinal = spritearray[i];
                sprite =  new labelBox(Ncardinal, radius, document.body);
                //this.marker = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.05, 30, 30));
                //this.marker.position.copy(sprite.position);
                //scene.add(marker);
                spriteboxes.push(sprite);
            }

            //var Ncardinal = {"name": "North", "lat":0, "lon": 10};
            //sprite =  new labelBox(Ncardinal, radius, document.body);


        }
    function animate() {

    spriteboxes.forEach(function(e) { e.update()} );
    sprite.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }
init();
animate();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid labels overlapping in javacript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590214/how-to-avoid-labels-overlapping-in-javacript)

Comment: @lakers1234 You should consider deleting that other question which is mostly identical.

Answer (score 0):

As your labels are not actually 3d-objects, this question has really nothing to do with 3d. What you need to do is this (this is a naive algorithm that works. Can certainly be optimized for a larger number of labels etc):

- 1.) find out the exact label-dimensions per label, store them somewhere (use `element.offsetWidth/Height`)
- 2.) compute the "anchor-position" per label, that is the screen-position
- 3.) place all labels using the following algorithm:

  - a) compute the region that is occupied by that label if placed at it's anchor-position (in terms of a Box, i.e. top/left, bottom/right - you could use the `THREE.Box2`-class to store that information)
  - b) test for intersections with all boxes already placed on screen (i.e. `box.intersectsBox(otherBox)`).
  - c) if there is no intersection, we have a placement for this box and can continue with the next box
  - d) if there is an intersection, find a place where the label could be placed, i'd simply try again some pixels up/down/left/right, depending on the relative placement of the labels and test again, make sure to abort (and simply skip the label) if you can't find a placement that works after a number of tries.

It will not always be possible to find a place for every label so it makes sense to order them by priority before starting to insert them.